# Memory hog on php script. Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, memory

I've a script for backup pourposes. Read a list user and after, make a backup.

I put a control before backup user, bceause I get some time a error memory (Allowed memory size exhausted)

Edited:
Question it's not about my code break... question it's about how can isolate problem, search problem, ... apreciate your help

```
foreach ($user_backup as $value) {
   ...
   //code for write (memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024/1024)
   self::BackupUser($value);
} 
...
private function BackupUser($user)
{
    // some code for 5 var text no more 10 charcters
    self::backupCpanelUser($user)!=0 ? exit : $op=0;  

    AnyClass::rsyncCpanelUser($user)!=0 ? exit : $op=0 ;

    $cmd =('rm -Rf '.$cfg['local_path'].'/'.$user);
    exec($cmd,$list);
    // @todo Gestion de error

    AnyClassSQL::editRowEnd('jobs',InitApp::$cfg_add['jobs_id'],time());

    return $op;
}
...
/**
 * @return string
 */
private function backupCpanelUser($user)
{
    //some code not uses var long
    return $op;
}
```

Well on my own logs

```
cat storage/logs/20151027173731.log|grep "Memory in use"|less
...
localhost - 2015-10-27 17:21:03 - 7 - Memory in use before backup ecotale is: 3.25Mib
localhost - 2015-10-27 17:22:06 - 7 - Memory in use before backup gktiledl is: 194.5Mib
localhost - 2015-10-27 17:22:17 - 7 - Memory in use before backup mnagixpy is: 194.5Mib
... 
localhost - 2015-10-27 17:27:20 - 7 - Memory in use before backup tejo is: 252.5Mib
localhost - 2015-10-27 17:27:31 - 7 - Memory in use before backup luchamos is: 252.5Mib
...
// App crash when get limit on 512M
```

I don't understand process well. I'm use php 5.3 (Cpanel's internal php version). And I think, whe a method end and return, memory used by method's var, it's delete (unlink)

Also I don't understand where script get 200 MB ram. On app not are to many uses of arrays. On all server taht use script memory show only 3Mb of use

Comment: Providing the `BackupUser()` method code would be useful and the rest of the loop code.

Comment: `backupCpanelUser` will always return `null`. Is that intended?

Comment: Thanks.. i search a way.. put code here, it's very long...

Comment: return a var (only line no more 255 characters)

Comment: We'd also need `AnyClassSQL::editRowEnd()` and `AnyClass::rsyncCpanelUser()`. My guess would be you need to release a database result after running a query.

Comment: You're going to need to do your own benchmarking to find what isn't cleaning up after itself. The code is shortly going to get too long for anyone to want to look at and it looks like it might be a 3rd party class?

Comment: AnyClass call a 3rd party class (dibi/dibi on packgist). But Database sqlite3 it's only for simple poruposes, and only has 1mb).